# Insert tomorrow's date in a VS Code Snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have an [Alfred Snippet](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/features/snippets/) that types the outline of a weekly Markdown checklist for me. Here's what it comes out looking like:

```
## Week (4/25–4/29)
- [ ] 

### Monday Apr 25, 2022
- [ ] Snippet

----
```

I'd like to move this over to a [VS Code Snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). VS Code defines environment variables like `$CURRENT_YEAR` and `$CURRENT_MONTH_NAME_SHORT` that can fill out some of this. But for the "Week (4/25-4/29)" line, I'd really like to have the date for the next Friday (usually four days from today). Is there any way to do this with a VS Code snippet?

For reference, this is how my Alfred is defined:

```
## Week ({date:M/d}–{date +4d:M/d})
- [ ] 

### Monday {date}
- [ ] Snippet

----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the VSC snippets it is not possible.

With the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) (v1.10.0) you can generate dates/times that are a particular offset from `now`.

You have to define your preferred `dateTimeFormat` setting.

Define the following setting (we have a named date format: `week-schedule`)

Can be Global or in your Workspace

```
  "templates.dateTimeFormat": {
    "locale": "en-US",
    "options": {
      "year": "numeric",
      "month": "2-digit",
      "day": "2-digit",
      "weekday": "long",
      "hour12": false,
      "hour": "2-digit",
      "minute": "2-digit",
      "second": "2-digit"
    },
    "template": "${month}/${day}"
    "week-schedule": {
      "options": {
        "year": "numeric",
        "month": "short",
        "day": "2-digit",
        "weekday": "long",
      },
      "template": "${weekday} ${month} ${day}, ${year}"
    }
  }
```

Define the following template (Global or in your Workspace)

**`week-schedule.md`**

```
##@@## ${dateTimeFormat#template=${year}-${month}-${day}#offset=+1WD0 +1D#}_${dateTimeFormat#template=${month}-${day}#offset=+1WD0 +5D#}${input#Additional#find=^(.+)$#replace=-$1#}
## Week (${dateTimeFormat:offset=+1WD0 +1D:}–${dateTimeFormat:offset=+1WD0 +5D:})
- [ ] 

### ${dateTimeFormat:week-schedule:offset=+1WD0 +1D:}
- [ ] Snippet

----

### ${dateTimeFormat:week-schedule:offset=+1WD0 +2D:}
- [ ] Snippet

----

### ${dateTimeFormat:week-schedule:offset=+1WD0 +3D:}
- [ ] Snippet

----

### ${dateTimeFormat:week-schedule:offset=+1WD0 +4D:}
- [ ] Snippet

----

### ${dateTimeFormat:week-schedule:offset=+1WD0 +5D:}
- [ ] Snippet

----
```

It will create a filename with the dates and some (optional) additional text.

The first line needs to be that long. The whole filename template must be on line 1.

The template can contain VSC snippets and input fields and a few other variables.

---

**Edit**

In v1.11.0 there is a command `templates.pasteTemplate` where you can insert a Template with a key binding

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+w",  // or any other combo
    "command": "templates.pasteTemplate",
    "args": {
      "text": [
        "## Week (${dateTimeFormat:week-schedule-head:offset=+1wd0 +1d:}–${dateTimeFormat:week-schedule-head:offset=+1wd0 +5d:})",
        "- [ ]",
        "",
        "### ${dateTimeFormat:week-schedule:offset=+1wd0 +1d:}",
        "- [ ] Snippet",
        "",
        "----"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are these templates for new documents, or will this let me insert the template into an existing document? I want to do the latter.

Comment: you can create a temporary new document and copy paste the content, I can try to create the option to generate the template result in the clipboard and you can paste it, or replace the current selection, or I add the dateTime variable to the Next-Snippet routine, so you can insert the template text with a VSC snippet and then use Next-Snippet to replace the dateTime variables

Comment: @danvk See my edit for v1.11.0, command `templates.pasteTemplate`